# Is it useful for users to have different UI of side menu in each page?

Tags: icons, menu, sidebar

This is what I got today while navigationg [agoda.com](http://agoda.com)

[image]

Here you can see same content but different presentation.
Does this help user?

Comment: What is the reason behind having to change the side-menu constantly? (both aesthetically and orders).

Comment: I can't say that this is an example of best practice, although there might be business or technical reasons behind the implementation. It is better not to assume, but it certainly makes sense to be consistent where possible.

Comment: Different UI for same elements is not useful. Consistent design is intuitive design and makes navigation easier.

Comment: The site as a whole (not just these menus) gives every indication of "we redesigned but didn't get around to updating the entire site".  This is unlikely to be intentional.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered best practice to keep navigation and other similar elements consistent throughout a site. Consistent navigation helps the user know where they are within the site at a glance and navigate with ease. Moving links and changing icons causes confusion. It's possible that particular site could be rolling out a new design or performing some sort of A/B testing, but it is definitely not best practice to change your navigation that much within one site.

For more reading, see #8 here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-ia-mistakes/
and also: http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-rules-for-modern-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Best practice dictates main menus are one of the elements that NEEDS to be constant across all your pages. It is the one thing users can rely on constantly to not change. This way they can track where they clicked and in what section of the website they are.